# Showing different stores based on customer group

Tags: magento2

On Magento 2.1.7, I want customers in the wholesale customer group to see our wholesale store, and I want everyone else to see the default retail store.

I already find https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2 and https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14936/showing-different-stores-based-on-customer-group that not compatible. But, I find this interesting page https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134808/magento-2-redirect-customer-to-custom-page-after-login

Could you tell me what to do, and the path to the eventuals files I'll have to edit. Since I cannot pay for an extension, I need a free solution.